# How to reduce multiple arrays to one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, reduce

Ignoring my data structure and just given a list of multiple numpy arrays (all arrays have the exact same size/shape):

```
list[0] = [[0, 2, 0], 
           [1, 3, 0]]

list[1] = [[0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 3]]

list[2] = [[5, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0]]
```

I want to reduce this list of arrays to only one array. Zero means there is no value. For every entry the only given value should be taken. There are no overlapping values. There is always only one assigned value in one array for a given position.

```
result: [[5, 2, 0]
         [1, 3, 3]]
```

---

In my case I have a dictionary with tuples as keys and arrays as values. The arrays are Boolean arrays. Every dict entry represents a special channel and at one specific position only one dict entry has the value `True`.
I now want to replace all `True` values by the dictionary keys and reduce this dictionary down to only one array.

For example (near my real data):

```
dict { (9, 2, 6): [[False, True],
                   [True, False]]
       (1, 5, 8): [[True, False],
                   [False, True]] }

result: [[(1, 5, 8),(9, 2, 6)]
         [(9, 2, 6),(1, 5, 8)]]
```

**How could this be done with list comprehension, a numpy function and/or map & reduce?**

---

First try:

At first I thought I could just turn my numpy arrays into 0 & 1 (`.astype(np.float32)`) and then just multiply these arrays with my key:

```
values_filled = [key_tuple * value_array for key_tuple, value_array in dict]
```

And then to just sum over all arrays:

```
final = reduce(lambda right, left: right + left, values_filled)
```

But this obviously doesn't work since my keys are tuples of values and not just numbers.

---

What I try to archive is to do the opposite of the following operation:

```
{color: np.all(mask, axis=-1) for (color, mask) in 
        ((color, segmentation == color) for color in colors) if mask.max()}
```

With this operation I take a segmented image and create a dictionary with predefined colors. The numpy arrays have True at every position where the color is equal to the color in the image at that position / equal to the key of the dictionary.

Now I want to reduce this dictionary back to an image (there where changes on the dictionary).

Comment: It's doable, but what have you tried?

Comment: @MooingRawr I don't have any approach to get going on this.

Comment: you have just normal python lists... nothing `numpy` like

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel The arrays are numpy arrays. I omitted this detail for simplicity in my examples.

Comment: if you are asking what direction you should take, that's opinionated and too broad. if you are asking how to do it without trying, you are asking us to write code for you, which SO isn't a code writing service. I'm sorry If I'm coming off as a bit hard, but rules are rules... :\ show some attempt (even if it's not right) and I'm sure you will yield quicker answers. (note I'm not flagging this, but I guess I'll just wait for an edit.)

Comment: @MooingRawr I already tried to think about a solution but I can't come up with anything. I don't even know what to google for. I would be happy with a answer linking me to any technique to do this. I don't expect some one to write the code for me. Just mentioning appropriate methods (from python, numpy, ....)

Comment: So, which one is more like your real data, the first examples or the second? Because the first can be easily accomplished with `numpy.where`, the second is a bit harder...

Comment: @Graipher The second one is near my real data.

Comment: Just to clarify, if your value `[[False, True], True, False]]` has `True` in it you need to replace it with a `key-tuple`, is that it ?

Comment: @Anthony It's hard to answer this question since it really depends on the wording. Only the True values should be replaced with the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question just requires an array sum:

```
In [167]: alist = [[[0, 2, 0], 
     ...:            [1, 3, 0]],[[0, 0, 0], 
     ...:            [0, 0, 3]],[[5, 0, 0], 
     ...:            [0, 0, 0]]]
     ...:            
In [168]: alist
Out[168]: [[[0, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3]], [[5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
In [169]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[169]: (3, 2, 3)
In [170]: np.array(alist).sum(axis=0)
Out[170]: 
array([[5, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 3]])
```

That takes advantage of the fact that 0 doesn't affect the sum, and there aren't any overlapping values.

---

You apparently have a second question involving a dictionary of boolean arrays or masks.  Assuming that's related to the first question, then you just need a way of translating those masks into the list of arrays (or lists) as given in the first.

---

Starting with the dictionary, we'll need to iterate over the keys (or items).  We can use the same summing.  After a little experimentation I decided `I,J=np.where(v)` was the easiest way of mapping the boolean mask on to the target array:

```
In [200]: dd={ (9, 2, 6): [[False, True],
     ...:                    [True, False]],
     ...:        (1, 5, 8): [[True, False],
     ...:                    [False, True]] }
     ...:                    
In [201]: arr = np.zeros((2,2,3),int)
In [202]: for k,v in dd.items():
     ...:     I,J = np.where(v)
     ...:     arr[I,J,:] += k
     ...: 
In [203]: arr
Out[203]: 
array([[[1, 5, 8],
        [9, 2, 6]],

       [[9, 2, 6],
        [1, 5, 8]]])
```

---

For the last iteration:

```
In [204]: k
Out[204]: (1, 5, 8)
In [205]: v
Out[205]: [[True, False], [False, True]]
In [206]: I,J=np.where(v)
In [207]: I,J
Out[207]: (array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
In [208]: arr[I,J,:]
Out[208]: 
array([[1, 5, 8],
       [1, 5, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without anything fancy, just good old for loops and list comprehension, and enumerate. I'm sure there's a better one liner out there or a library that can cover it, but here's a vanilla Python solution :

```
d = { (9, 2, 6): [[False, True],[True, False]],(1, 5, 8): [[True, False],[False, True]] }

new_list = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if new_list:
        for i, each in enumerate(v):
            x = [k if z else new_list[i][j] for j,z in enumerate(each)]
            new_list[i] = x
    else:
        for each in v:
            new_list.append([k if x else x for x in each])

print(new_list) # [[(1, 5, 8), (9, 2, 6)], [(9, 2, 6), (1, 5, 8)]]
```

P.S. also thank you for showing your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Another `numpy` approach, in case you want it to be a normal `numpy` array afterwards:

```
import numpy as np

d = {(9, 2, 6): [[False, True],
                 [True, False]],
     (1, 5, 8): [[True, False],
                 [False, True]]}
x = np.sum(np.reshape(k, (1,1,-1)) * np.array(v)[..., None]  for k, v in d.items())
# x = np.sum(np.array(k)[None, None, :] * np.array(v)[..., None] for k, v in d.items())    # Alternative way
print(X)
# array([[[1, 5, 8],
#         [9, 2, 6]],
#        [[9, 2, 6],
#         [1, 5, 8]]])
np.all(x == np.array([[(1, 5, 8),(9, 2, 6)], [(9, 2, 6),(1, 5, 8)]]))
# True
```

This basically uses the approach you outlined in your question, of multiplying the truth mask with the value. I just added the fact that the content of that value is another (third) dimension and used `numpy`s broadcasting features to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Numpythonic approach:

```
arr = np.dstack((lst1, lst2, lst3)) # Create columns along the first axis
mask = arr.astype(bool) # create a mask from places that are nonzero
mask2 = (~mask).all(axis=-1) # another mask that gives rows that are all zero
mask[mask2] = [True, False, False] # Truthify one optional item in all-zero rows 
result = arr[mask].reshape(lst1.shape) # get the desire items and reshape
```

Demo:

```
In [135]: arr = np.dstack((lst1, lst2, lst3))

In [136]: arr
Out[136]: 
array([[[0, 0, 5],
        [2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 0]]])

In [137]: mask = arr.astype(bool)

In [138]: mask2 = (~mask).all(axis=-1)

In [139]: mask[mask2] = [True, False, False]

In [140]: arr[mask].reshape(lst1.shape)
Out[140]: 
array([[5, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 3]])
```